# How to stop bokeh from opening a new tab in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

First of all, before this is tagged as duplicate, I have read the other solutions and unfortunately none of them worked for me.

My problem is that I want to display a bokeh plot in Juypter Notebook (and only in Jupyter Notebook), not in a new  tab/window.

In the official documentation [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#inline-plots) I am told that I only need to change

```
output_file
```

to

```
output_notebook
```

Even though the plot **is** now displayed inline if I do that, bokeh won't stop also opening a new tab and needlessly displaying the plot there.

Since I'm gonna create lots of plots in my project, it'd be very nice to not always have to close this new tab and return to notebook, but just have it stop creating new tabs, just as it would work with e.g. matplotlib.

What confuses me is that if I load up the [official tutorial](https://hub.mybinder.org/user/bokeh-bokeh-notebooks-obozp12q/notebooks/tutorial/02%20-%20Styling%20and%20Theming.ipynb) and enter code there, for example

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.exp(x)

p = figure()
p.line(x, y)

show(p)
```

there is no new tab opened. If I now run the same code locally on my machine's Juypter Notebook, it **does** open up a new tab.

I've been trying for a while now to fix this, any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Vincent

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to call `output_notebook` at the top of your notebook, but *only* call `output_notebook`. If you call `output_file` at all, that activates a persistent mode that saves output to files, and causes `show` to open new tabs with those files. You would need to call `reset_output` to clear that persistent mode.

As a convenience, since several users asked for it, if *no* output mode is supplied, `show` behaves as though `output_file` was called as a default. The reason a tab is not opened from the Binder tutorial is because it is not technically possible for code running remotely on Binder server to open a tab on your local browser (which is a very good thing).

Comment: Every time a tab is opened using output_file, the browser automatically switches to it. There a way to disable that (run the code without auto switching)? Switch to new tab when opened is off in my firefox browser.

Comment: You can pass `new="window"` to `show` a new window intead of a tab, but what gets focused is up to the browser/OS and not something Bokeh can control. Your other option is just to `save` to a file without opening a tab or a window.

Answer (score 20):

Adding an explicit example to @bigreddot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51523795/5717580):

You might have ran `bokeh.io.output_file()` somewhere in your notebook, to save noteable graphs. However, now you only want to experiment with some plots quickly to inspect the data.

Simply **reset** your settings to stop saving to file in any cell in your notebook like so:

```
import bokeh.io
# this is here only for completeness to clarify where
# the methods are nested (you probably already imported this earlier)


bokeh.io.reset_output()
bokeh.io.output_notebook()
```

You can activate saving to file again later to keep the interesting graphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can import:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import output_notebook
```

And call `output_notebook` before your `figure`s declaration, then you just show the figure using `show`. See the [doc](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/1.3.2/docs/user_guide/notebook.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this question was closed over two years ago :D