# jupyterlab: bokeh plot displays in wrong browser

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a VM running jupyterlab and have opened it up for external access.  When jupyter-lab starts, a local browser opens up, which is fine.

Externally, I access jupyterlab and things appear to work.  However, when I plot, the output doesn't show up in the browser but instead appears as a new tab in the *local browser which started up with jupyter-lab*.

The same thing happens if I have `%matplotlib inline`.

The following is a little better in that now things display inline.  However, a new tab still opens up in the *other* browser.

```
%matplotlib inline
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

output_notebook()

colormap = {'setosa': 'red', 'versicolor': 'green', 'virginica': 'blue'}
colors = [colormap[x] for x in flowers['species']]

p = figure(title = "Iris Morphology")
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Length'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Width'

p.circle(flowers["petal_length"], flowers["petal_width"],
        color=colors, fill_alpha=0.2, size=10)

# output_file("iris.html", title="iris.py example")

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to my setup but instead simply to my lack of understanding regarding Bokeh.  Bokeh has state.  So, if you call output_file() or maybe even if not, it saves all your plots which causes them to also display in a new browser tab.  The solution is to not do that :)

Putting the following code at the top of the example cell above fixed the issue:

```
bokeh.io.reset_output()
bokeh.io.output_notebook()
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51512907/2184122).  Thank you bigreddot and martin-martin

Technically, mine is a duplicate question.  However it was non-obvious enough that I'll leave it around.